# how to allow recaptcha through localhost proxy

Tags: windows, recaptcha, http-proxy, grecaptcha

As some context, I work at a showroom for an online business that has a few computers for the customers to access the website. In a recent windows update, kiosk mode broke. To lock down the browser I figured I could make all, but a few specific websites go through a localhost proxy with 127.0.0.1 with a lot of success. The only reason I cannot implement this solution to the showroom computers is because recaptcha doesn't load. These are the following urls I've added in an attempt to "allow" recaptcha to connect the the internet:

1. google.com/recaptcha/
2. gstatic.com/recaptcha/
3. recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/